# Vim: call object method in a custom function

Tags: vim

I'm using neovim with the [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) autocompletion plugin. I don't like the auto-auto complete, so I am trying to get completion to work using `<Tab>`. As the docs suggest:

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <Tab>
    \ pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : deoplete#manual_complete()
```

This works great ... except that `<Tab>` does not indent anymore even if I am at the start of a line (or there is a space under the cursor). I've written a function (poorly) to get around this:

```
function! Smart_TabComplete()
    if pumvisible()
        return "^N"
    endif
    let line = getline('.')                         " current line

    let substr = strpart(line, -1, col('.')+1)      " from the start of the current
    " line to one character right
    " of the cursor
    let spaces = strpart(line, -1, col('.'))

    let substr = matchstr(substr, '[^ \t]*$')       " word till cursor
    let spaces = matchstr(spaces, '[^ \t]*$')
    if (strlen(substr)==0)                          " nothing to match on empty string
        return "        "
    endif
    if (strlen(spaces)==0)                          " nothing to match on empty string
        return "        "
    endif
    deoplete#manual_complete()
endfunction
```

I call this instead of `deoplete#manual_complete()` above. Seemingly this fixes the using `<Tab>` for indent problem, but now inside the function I always get:

> `Not an editor command: deoplete#manual_complete()`

I'm not really sure what to do about this, and I even tried passing `deoplete` in as an argument to `Smart_TabComplete`, but it doesn't work.

- Is there a better way to use `<Tab>` for both autocomplete and spacing?
- Otherwise, how can I call `deoplete#manual_complete()` in my custom function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `:call` command to call a function.

```
call deoplete#manual_complete()
```

If you need to return the results of `deoplete#manual_complete()` then use `:return`:

```
return deoplete#manual_complete()
```

For more help see:

```
:h :call
:h :return
```

Comment: This does result in calling the function, but it seems to just use the return value of the function `0` rather than actually proxying to the `deoplete` function call.  Any suggestions?